# How to post javascript image file to ActionResult with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, image

I've created a function that enables the user to draw on a canvas. Afterwards I turn this canvas in an image .PNG file with the following code

```
function saveCanvas() {
        var link = document.createElement('a');

        link.innerHTML = 'download image';
        link.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
            link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
            link.download = "mypainting.png";
        }, false);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
    }
```

This function allows me to save the canvas.toDataURL() locally on the hard drive, however I want to pass the javascript file to an ActionResult and turn it into a c# object so that I can store the image in a database using c#.

Comment: Why don't u save the image in server and path in the database?

Comment: you can convert the canvas to Blob using toBlob() method and pass the blob to controller or convert the blob to base 64 string and send to controller.

Comment: And how would I send it to the controller after converting it to a Blob?

Comment: put it in a hidden input type and submit the form or send a xhr call.

Comment: If  I were to put it into a hidden input, which datatype in c# do i need to store the canvas?

Comment: You could use IFormFile